# Json_encoded value is not updating to database

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I am creating code where i am updating a table where a json_encoded value return with this code

```
global $wpdb;    
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ab_payments';
$test = '{"items":[{"ca_id":1,"appointment_date":"2016-11-04 08:00:00","service_name":"wordpress developer","service_price":"10.00","deposit":"100%","number_of_persons":"1","staff_name":"admin","extras":[]}],"coupon":{"code":"5off","discount":"50","deduction":"0.00"},"customer":"admin"}';

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET details='$test' WHERE id LIKE '$paymentid'"));
```

but the problem is its not updating database value. if replace value with simple text its working fine but with test json_encoded value is not updating please help.

thank you

Comment: You're dumping in arbitrary data without escaping and there's no way this will work. You need to [properly escape your input using placeholder values](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders) using the WordPress database layer.

Comment: @tadman Hi just wrote simple query for test if its update value in database but its not working. You are saying that i should create query like this example:- 

$metakey = "Harriet's Adages";
$metavalue = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
 "
  INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
  ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
  VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
 ", 
        10, 
 $metakey, 
 $metavalue 
) );

Comment: Yes, you use placeholders like `%s` and the WPDB library takes care of the rest.

Comment: @tadman also json econded value are correct and working fine. just wrote in variable so i can show you guys what encoded value is inserting

Comment: @tadman is this correct $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
 "
  INSERT INTO $wpdb->ab_payments
  ( details)
  VALUES ( %d )
  WHERE id LIKE %d
 ", 
 mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($deserialized)),
 $paymentid
) );

Comment: You shouldn't be using any of the `mysql_query` family of functions. Let the WPDB layer do the escaping for you, and use `%s` for string values. `%d` is for numbers.

Comment: @tadman i am trying but unable to create code can you please create code for me

Comment: The WordPress documentation is full of examples.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @tadman its wordpress placeholder which require to update json_encode code so updated code with this and start working.

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET details=%s WHERE id=%d",$serialized,$paymentid));
```